# MONGODB store value in variable to use later

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

i have a code that inserts information from a 3rd party API every 24hours the api information is ***ID, Name, Status, Position, Score*** the only information that can get updated if there is any change are ***Name, Status, Position, Score***, ID will always be the same.

I'm trying to show information based on if there is any change when new data is inserted to the database for example

```
08/14/2022 ------------- 08/15/2022
Name: yandr1 ========== NO CHANGES
position    1 ========== NO CHANGES
id  123 ========== NO CHANGES 
score   100 ========== CHANGES TO: 200 ( POINTS GAINED 100 )
```

based on the new data inserted to MongoDB Database Score changed from 100 to 200, how can i show on the website the OLD SCORE AND POINTS GAINED? ***Position, Name,old score, POINTS GAINED***

[image: so it looks something like this]

***CODE TO INSERT DATA INTO DB FROM API***

```
//POST DAILY PLAYERS DATA//

cron.schedule('56 23 * * *', async () => {

    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },

    });

    const Post = mongoose.model('players', postSchema);

    async function getPosts() {
        const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/players");
        const response = await getPlayers.json();
        for (let i = 0; i < response.players.length; i++) {

            const post = new Post({
                id: response.players[i]['id'],
                name: response.players[i]['name'],
                status: response.players[i]['status'],
            });
            post.save();


        }

    }
    console.log("Table submitted successfully")

    await getPosts();

});


//POST DAILY HIGHSCORE DATA//

cron.schedule('55 23 * * *', async () => {

    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        position: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        score: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },

    });

    const Post = mongoose.model('highscores', postSchema);

    async function getPosts() {
        const getHighscore = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players");
        const response = await getHighscore.json();
        for (let i = 0; i < response.players.length; i++) {

            const post = new Post({
                position: response.players[i]['position'],
                id: response.players[i]['id'],
                score: response.players[i]['score'],
            });
            post.save();


        }

    }
    console.log("Table submitted successfully")

    await getPosts();

});
```

```
router.get('/export', async function(req, res, next) {
   let data
   try {
      data = await Promise.all([
         Posts.list(),
         Events.list(),
         Messages.list(),
         Users.list()
      ]);
   // at this point, data is an array. data[0] = Posts.list result, data[1] = Events.list result etc..
   res.status(200).json(data)
   } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send('error');  
   }    
});
```

Comment: Hey Yandry please share the code that save the data in API. Thanks

Comment: Hey Yandra you didn't create schema for point, then how you can save the data in it...

Comment: schema for point? what do you mean? im pretty new to mongodb and this code works for me, the api that i fetch from updates every 24hrs, and i have this code everyday at 12am it inserts new information from third api to mongodb so it works for me

Comment: Oh sorry i think you wanna create new.. Sorry lemme answer this. Thanks

Comment: no, what i want to do is store a value into a variable

Comment: If you wanna show old score and new score, best thing is to first create schema for both of them.

Comment: thanks for your answer i will try your code now, i updated my post with a code that i found on another answer, would that code work? to show old score and new score? i have an schema for both of them i have one called "topnames" and other called "topscore"

Comment: Hey Yandry, i checked above you didn't post any code that shows schema for oldScore and newScores.. Thanks

Comment: just updated code, check now please thanks! i have codes like that because there are two different 3rd party apis, the api#1 gives me id,name,status and api#2 gives me same id, position and score.

Comment: okay can you please contact me on tele or some where else because it's bit lengthy then regular code.. but if you still need here, then i will give you an idea.. 
Thanks

Comment: do you have discord?

Comment: Yes, hypervarun #6188

Comment: it says your not accepting friend request please add me brother thanks! yandr1#1755

Answer (score 1):

Hey Yandry try this code-

```
async function getPosts() {
const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/players");
const response = await getPlayers.json();
for( let i = 0;i < response.players.length; i++){
id= response.players[i]['id'];
name= response.players[i]['name'];
status= response.players[i]['status'];
const updateScore = await findOneAndUpdate({id:id},{$set:{name:name,status:status}})
console.log("Updated Score",updateScore)
}
}
```

Please, try this code, hope you will get solution, if you still facing issue just lemme know, i will help you more.
Thank